# Some doubts about Spring namespace into XML configuration file. How exactly works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xml-namespaces

I am pretty new in Spring and I have a little doubt related the concept of namespace into my XML configuration files.

So for example into the **root-context.xml** file of a project on which I am working on there is this definition:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDbDS" id="datasource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

that have the **jee** namepace that is also specified into the **beans** external container by:

```
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
```

Now my doubt is, what exactly is this definition having id="datasource"? This one:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDbDS" id="datasource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Is it a classic bean of Spring having a specific namespace because it belong to a specific domain of bean (having a specific pourpose) or what?

Comment: It's just an id to your bean, which in this case is obtained from a JNDI resource. You can then use this bean on an @Autowired field for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Explained in the spring doc:

> The jee tags deal with Java EE (Java Enterprise Edition)-related
>   **configuration** issues, such as looking up a JNDI object and defining
>   EJB references

Here after an example from spring doc:

**Without using jee jndi-lookup**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/MyDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.foo.JdbcUserDao">
    <!-- Spring will do the cast automatically (as usual) -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

**Using jee jndi-lookup**

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MyDataSource"/>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.foo.JdbcUserDao">
    <!-- Spring will do the cast automatically (as usual) -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

More details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html)